# BDD Visualization with IPython and GraphViz

Tags: python

I'm Trying to work with PyEDA, i need to visualize Binary Decision Diagram, i'm reading this document but i can't understand it!

here it says: If you have GraphViz installed on your machine, and the dot executable is available on your shell’s path, you can use the gvmagic IPython extension to visualize BDDs.

first of all, how can i make the dot executable available on my shell's path?

then, in the document we have this part:

```
In [1]: %install_ext https://raw.github.com/cjdrake/ipython-magic/master/gvmagic.py

In [2]: %load_ext gvmagic
```

is this the DOT environment?

sorry if the questions are so simple and stupid! i'm not so professional in using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

To install GraphViz and make the dot executable available on my shell's path you have to install the Ubuntu package `graphviz`.

"[dot](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dot.1.html)" is a non-interactive program for drawing directed graphs from a textual description and is part of GraphViz. The dot executable is installed as `/usr/bin/dot`.

The `%install_ext` thing is the [IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) shell. It's available as Ubuntu package `python3-ipython`. You can start it from the command line using the command

```
ipython3
```

Comment: What is the problem with this?
can you help me?

i typed this:
In [1]: %install_ext https://raw.github.com/cjdrake/ipython-magic/master/gvmagic.py

but this is the answer!
UsageError: Line magic function `%install_ext` not found.

Comment: It seems recent versions of IPython don't support `%install_ext` any more. Install the Ubuntu package `python3-pip`  and use `pip3 install --user gvmagic` from the shell instead.